# How to identify element with knowledge of partial text for any tag (eg. div,span etc.) contains?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, java, ie8

My source goes like this:

```
<div name="something" id="something"....>IPS125</div>
```

the number after IPS always changes. So I need to give the identification attribute as partial text "IPS".
(name and id are horribly changing every time I open source.)

Answer (score 6):

Use `contains()` or `starts-with()` function in XPath:

**Solution :**

With `contains()`:

```
//*[contains(@id,'IPS')]
```

With `starts-with()`:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'IPS')]
```

Where `*` means any element.
Let me know If any query.

Answer (score 3):

You should use xpath. If your text 'IPS' is the text inside tag use this: `//*[contains(.,'IPS')]`.

If 'IPS' is for example part of @class atrribute use this: `//*[contains(@class,'IPS')]`.

If 'IPS' is always at the begginig of the text you can use `starts-with` command instead of `contains`.

Unfortunately web browsers dont support Xpath 2.0 which provides regular expressions.

Comment: After the edit the answer is quite simple. Use the first option from my answer: `//div[contains(.,'IPS')]`

Answer (score 0):

I use this function with good results:

```
    static WebElement getElementsWithAlteratingNames(String PartialName, String Tag, WebDriver driver, String Attribute) {
    try {
        List<WebElement> Elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(Tag));
        String[] ElementStrings = new String[Elements.size()];
        System.out.println(Elements.size());
        for (int LoopCounter = 0; LoopCounter < Elements.size(); LoopCounter++) {
            ElementStrings[LoopCounter] = Elements.get(LoopCounter).getAttribute(Attribute).toString();
            if (ElementStrings[LoopCounter].contains(PartialName)) {
                System.out.println(ElementStrings[LoopCounter]);
                return Elements.get(LoopCounter);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not generate a list of elements");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've kept it fairly abstract so you can easily costumize it to serve the individual needs of your wanted Element.

**Update**

Since the Method is just not good and throws away efficiency if made a small update that does pretty much the same:

```
static WebElement findElem(String Tag, String Att, String Value){ 
    List<WebElement>Elems = driver.findElements(By.tagName(Tag)); 
       for(WebElement Elem : Elems){ 
           if(Elem.getAttribute(Att).contains(Value)) return Elem; 
       }
     }
```

Since the code above isn't something that would pass a code review if one of my team did it I wouldn't feel good to leave it that way.

Comment: what is `Elemente` in `Elemente.get(LoopCounter).getAttribute`?  If you would, include import statements.

Comment: Elements, it should be Elements. I guess my german broke through. I'll edit it, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That method makes me dizzy, lol.

Comment: That's because, looking at it now, it's just not good. 
static WebElement findElem(String Tag, String Att, String Value){
List<WebElement>Elems = driver.findElements(By.tagName(Tag));
for(WebElement Elem : Elems){
     if(Elem.getAttribute(Att).contains(Value)) return Elem;
}
}
is much more concise and leaves out all the useless boilerplate.