# How do I identify a specific <div> by id with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver, css

I want to grab everything within this `div` with an `id` of "storytext":

```
<!-- END ID="STORY-META" CLASS="STORY-META" -->
<div id="storytext" class="storytext storylocation linkLocation">
      <p>NPR's Ari Shapiro talks with <em>Washington Post</em> reporter David Weigel about the conspiracy behind Democratic National Committee staffer Seth Rich's murder last summer and how fake news is still spreading.</p>
</div>
<div class="transcript storytext" aria-label="Transcript">
    <b class="icn-story-transcript-wrap">
        <b class="icn-story-transcript"></b>
    </b>
```

Trying to grab this div:

```
public void init(Properties p) {
    log.info(p.toString());
    String url = p.getProperty("url");
    String tagNameString = p.getProperty("tagNameString");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    log.info(pageSource);
    log.info("done");
    log.info(tagNameString);
    List<WebElement> listOfWebElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName(tagNameString));
    log.info(listOfWebElements.toString());
}
```

Execution log:

```
    window.onload = (typeof window.onload != 'function') ?
            loadChartbeat : function() {
        oldonload();
        loadChartbeat();
    };
})();
</script><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://static.chartbeat.com/js/chartbeat.js"></script></body></html>
Jul 12, 2017 8:11:59 PM net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Scraper init
INFO: done
Jul 12, 2017 8:11:59 PM net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Scraper init
INFO: storytext
Jul 12, 2017 8:12:12 PM net.bounceme.dur.web.selenium.Scraper init
INFO: []
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/selenium$
```

whether to iterate, parse or persist.  Playing with Selenium.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/20136/8900   but more complete answer appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> // tagNameString is equal to "storytext"
> driver.findElements(By.tagName(tagNameString));
> ```

What you are actually asking Selenium to do is to find all "storytext" elements. Selenium will be looking for `<storytext>...</storytext>` elements which, I am pretty sure, you have none.

Instead, you intended to use the "by id" locator:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.id(tagNameString));
```